# plot.igraph parameters ignored

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I'm trying to plot a graph with the `igraph` package in R. Oddly enough the first two parameters (`vertex.color` and `edge.arrow.size`) work, but other parameters that I include from the `igraph.plotting` documentation (like `label`) are ignored. In this example, labels should disappear from nodes but they don't, either using `plot` or `plot.igraph`.

Any idea why it isn't working?

```
library(igraph)

g<-make_full_graph(5) %du% make_full_graph(5) %du% make_full_graph(5)
g<-add_edges(g,c(1,6,1,11,6,11))

plot(g,vertex.color=c(rep("blue",5),rep("red",5),rep("yellow",5)),edge.arrow.size=0.2,label=NA)
```

Comment: You need `vertex.label` not just `label`